# Beginner looking for advice/help on this code (Python)

Tags: python, loops, logic

I've started the MIT open course for beginners (its in Python) and the first assignment is: 
*Write a program that computes and prints the 1000th prime number.*

I have started to do it on my own with the things learned in the lectures, but after a few attempts at nested loops, I can't seem to produce any working code. Can I have any tips, have my errors pointed out?

```
divisor = 1
result = 2
odds = 1
total = 1

# all odd int generation

for x in range(100):
    total = total + 1

# test for each generated number

    for n in range(1, total / 2):
        if (result % divisor != 0):
            print "result: ", result, " is prime!"
    odds = odds + 2
    result = odds
```

It is incomplete, but even this part doesn't work for me.

Comment: You don't do anything with `divisor` or `result`, so they are always 1 and 2 respectively. Did you mean to use `x % n` in the if statement?

Comment: you are right, i've missed a bunch of stuff, ill review it myself a few more times and ask again if i get stumped, thanks!

Comment: Try to follow [Python Enhancement Proposal 8 aka PEP8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) when writing Python code. It's a convention designed for the standard library but pretty much the whole community use it. (In your case you are not using the proper whitespaces between operators and comas)

Comment: Thanks, I'll go trought that now.